# Как отредактировать тему Вордпресса ?

Tags: wordpress

Раньше работал на движке DLE, теперь перешел на Вордпресс, и передо мной встал вопрос- "Как редактировать тему вордпресса", пожалуйста, помогите, не могу удалить левые ссылки из темы.

Answer (score 1):

Что за левые ссылки? Если вы имеете ввиду это (смотри снимок), то все очень просто, в админ панели заходите в Внешний вид - Виджеты, и там справа у вас стоят эти виджеты, просто удаляете их, а точнее удаляете не нужны, только есть один нюанс, если удалить все, то появятся другие =) что бы такого не было, поставьте один виджет - Произвольный текст, и ни чего в нем не пишите, и все.

Так же, если у вас "Сложная тема" то часть ее настроек и ссылок в частности может находится непосредственно в настройках темы (на против темы появляется ссылка "Настройки")

[image]